# Responsive content inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have written a web tool that helps designers create templates. They fix some things, and they reload the template with some data. The template is rendered inside an iframe, and I've added a control to change the iframe's width.

When I change the iframe's width, the content doesn't look responsive, even if I reload the iframe contents. However, if I render the same content in a new window, instead of inside the iframe, resizing the browser window makes content adapt, so there is no problem with the HTML/CSS of the designers.

So, how do I make responsive content adapt to the iframe width?

Comment: Do you have a demo? Have you set the viewport metatag in the content iframe?

Comment: The iframe is created automatically by assembling our template with some  data and generating an HTML, that is put exactly as is inside the iframe. I must not change this HTML, since it will be the same that runs on mobile devices, desktop computers and so forth. So no, I don't set any thing inside the iframe.

Comment: I can't add shots for non-disclosure reasons ;)